# find records by element of array string

Tags: c#, mongodb

I tried to find all records in collection by specific array element(underlined in blue):
[image]

This is my code:

```
    FilterDefinition<string> queryTemplate = Builders<string>.Filter.Eq(pr => pr, templateId);
    return Database.GetCollection<AutoSave>(MongoDb.AutoSaveCollection)
        .Find(Builders<AutoSave>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Templates, queryTemplate)).ToList();
```

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the following filter a try:

```cs
    var filter = Builders<AutoSave>.Filter.Where(s => s.Templates.Contains(templateId));

    var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

here's a [test program](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/5d36e976ef3b1e5f598947b0b34aa279)